# Visual Studio, Xamarin Forms, creating .resx file isn't creating Designer.cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization, resx

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217173/do-i-need-the-resx-designer-cs-file) post about `.resx` files having a corresponding `.designer.cs` file that is generated when you create a new `.resx` file in Xamarin studio. I am using `.resx` for [localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/) in my Xamarin shared project.

Unfortunately [as of 24 Aug 2017 and version 15.3.2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/85616/add-new-item-resource-file-resx-missing.html) , it seems that you are no longer able to create a `.resx` file through the `Add->new item` solution wizard.

One [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505696/xamarin-forms-cannot-add-resx-for-globalization) is to create a .resx file outside of VS, and then use the `Add->Existing Item` solution wizard, and the `.designer.cs`  file is supposedly generated automatically. (**this did not work for me**)

Another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473315/visual-studio-cant-find-resource-file-in-list-of-items-to-add-to-project) is to change the file format of a `.txt` file in the solution wizard, and then run the custom tool `ResXFileCodeGenerator` in the `AppResources` property field. (**This also did not work for me**)

One final solution I found is to [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729255/programmatically-generate-designer-cs-for-resx-file-resxresourcewriter-resxreso) create the designer file, but I couldn't get this code to run, and surely there is a better solution.

## So my question is:

 
What is the correct way to create a `AppResources.resx` file, with a corresponding `AppResources.designer.cs` file in **Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.7.3**